# Выход в интернет через IPIP туннель

Tags: linux, сеть, ip, openvpn, ipip

Здравствуйте. Суть такова: надо настроить выход в интернет одной сети на машине через IPIP.

Предположим, шлюз имеет внешний IP 1.1.1.1, а подключаемая машина 2.2.2.2

В машине есть сеть с IP 192.168.222.0 -- эту сеть нужно вывести в интернет через шлюз 1.1.1.1. При этом машина 2.2.2.2 выходит в интернет через собственный канал. Как это сделать с помощью IPIP?

Настройка тоннеля на шлюзе:

```
ip tunnel add ipip0 mode ipip remote 2.2.2.2 local 1.1.1.1 dev eth0
ifconfig ipip0 10.1.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 pointopoint 10.1.0.2
ifconfig ipip0 mtu 1500 up
```

Настройка тоннеля на хосте:

```
ip tunnel add ipip0 mode ipip remote 1.1.1.1 local 2.2.2.2 dev eth0
ifconfig ipip0 10.1.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 pointopoint 10.1.0.1
ifconfig ipip0 mtu 1500 up
```

Соответственно IP тоннеля у шлюза 10.1.0.1, у хоста -- 10.1.0.2

Настройка iptables у шлюза:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/30 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1
```

Настройка iptables у хоста:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.222.0/24 ! -d 192.168.222.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.0.2
```

Ну и настройка ip route, rule:

```
ip route add default via 10.1.0.1 table 130
ip route add 192.168.222.0/24 via 192.168.222.1 table 130
ip rule add from 192.168.222.0/24 table 130
```

Что получается в итоге? На машинах сети я выхожу через IP 1.1.1.1, однако, сайты в браузерах не открываются. Но ping работает. При чем, я могу пинговать как по IP, так и хосту, значит, DNS работает.

Если использовать OpenVPN для создания тоннеля, то всё работает отлично.

Где я накосячил?

Comment: На обоих машинах попробуйте сделать `iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp` и возможно придется уменьшить MTU на туннелях

Comment: Спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло добавление в iptables:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp
```

Спасибо [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) за правильный ответ!